# Responsive design 3 div across layout with ul stacked underneath center div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to have a 3 div, 1 list, set up for my footer.  A link on the left, a title in the middle above my social media icons both centered, then another link to the right of them exactly as pictured.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Qur.jpg

I managed to accomplish this with some very badly written code.  I won't even show you the css.  It was bad.

```
  <div class="contentFoot">
    <ul>
      <li class="joinCommunity">Join our community</li>
      <li class="leftFoot"><a class="contentFootLink" href="sign-up">Sign up for email updates</a></li>
      <li>
        <ul class="soc">
          <li><a class="soc-twitter" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-facebook" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-google" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-pinterest" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-instagram soc-icon-last" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <a class="contentFootLink" href="feedback"><li class="rightFoot">Give us feedback about our website</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I'm now trying a rewrite in order to have a responsive design.  Here is what I'm trying now with my rewrite  I'm attempting to have div-inlineblock, div-inlineblock, div-block, div-inlineblock; so it would be left, middle stacked, right.  Then it will be easy to have the responsive design just stack everything when it is small enough.

Current state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pzJw.jpg

HTML:

```
      <div class="contentFoot">
        <div class="leftFoot">Sign up for email updates</div>
        <div class="midFoot">Join our community</div>
        <ul class="soc">
          <li><a class="soc-twitter" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-facebook" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-google" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-pinterest" href="#"></a></li>
          <li><a class="soc-instagram soc-icon-last" href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="rightFoot">Give us feedback about our website</div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```css
/************* footer ***************/
.contentFoot {
text-align:center;
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}

.leftFoot,
.midFoot,
.rightFoot {
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 25%;
}

/***************Social Media****************/
@font-face {
    font-family: 'si';
    src: url('font/socicon.eot');
    src: url('font/socicon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/socicon.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/socicon.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/socicon.svg#icomoonregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family:si;
        src: url(font/socicon.svg) format(svg);
    }
}

.soc {
    display: block;
    list-style:none;
    width: 20%;
    clear: both;
}
.soc li {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    zoom:1;
}
.soc li a {
    font-family:si!important;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
        transition:.1s;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.soc a:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.soc-icon-last{
    margin:0 !important;
}
.soc-twitter {
    background-color: #4da7de;
}
.soc-twitter:before {
    content:'a';
}
.soc-facebook {
    background-color: #3e5b98;
}
.soc-facebook:before {
    content:'b';
}
.soc-google {
    background-color: #d93e2d;
}
.soc-google:before {
    content:'c';
}
.soc-pinterest {
    background-color: #c92619;
}
.soc-pinterest:before {
    content:'d';
}
.soc-instagram {
    background-color: #9c7c6e;
}
.soc-instagram:before {
    content:'x';
}
```

Edit: setting .soc to include margin:0 auto; puts it in its proper position, but everything else is still out of alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve the desired design is to move the social icons *inside* the middle section and set the sections to be `33.333%` of the width:

**HTML**

```
<div class="midFoot">Join our community
          <ul class="soc">
            <li><a class="soc-twitter" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="soc-facebook" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="soc-google" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="soc-pinterest" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="soc-instagram soc-icon-last" href="#"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftFoot,
.midFoot,
.rightFoot {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

Then remove some of the browser default styles for lists:

```
.soc {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I also added `font-size: 0;` to `.contentFoot`, and then set the `font-size` specifically on the footer sections. This is a common trick to remove the whitespace that is added between `inline-block` elements. 
Another option would be to float the elements.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1o7h28bL/)